# Close tab programmatically TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

How can I close tab in TabHost? (My tab this Activity).
When I try:

```
tabHost.removeViewAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab());
```

My app crashs.

Comment: Which error do you get? Please add a logcat output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

`tabHost.getTabWidget().removeView(tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tab_index));`

Where `tab_index` is the index of the tab that you want to remove.

Comment: Thanks!Help me again please ;) How hide all tab captions ?

Comment: @D.D.M. How to hide the tab captions?