# Android Closing tab in tabHost

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I am developing chat application using android. Programmatically now I am able to add no of tab as per necessary. But problem is that I am unable to close a single tab. `tabhost.clearAllTabs` closes all tabs. I want to close particular tab when another user left chat window. 
Is it possible using tabhost? though there is no direct way to close tab is there any indirect way to close tab?

Thank you.

Update:

```
TabHost tabHost;
public class TActivity extends TabActivity {

    tabHost = getTabHost();                 
}

public void addTAb(){

        TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("counter:"+counter);    

        View tab = LayoutInflater.from(getTabHost().getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab, null);              
        tabSpec.setIndicator(tab);          
        Intent tabIntent = new Intent(this, Foo.class);
        tabSpec.setContent(tabIntent);  

        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);        

        tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(--);
        tabCounter = tabCounter +1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this code:

```
myTabhost.getTabWidget()
    .removeView(myTabhost.getTabWidget()
    .getChildTabViewAt(myTab)); // myTab is the one you want to close
```

I saw this on this question: [Close tab programmatically TabHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12587965/close-tab-programmatically-tabhost)

Hope you'll have the expected result.

Comment: friend, its not working. Where should I paste this code, in 'tabActivity' or 'Intent activity'. Also I am using custom tabwidget. I have put small imageview of 'close button' there. When someone click on this view, is it possible to close tab? & How to differentiate this 'close button' for every tab to bind?

Comment: I think you should paste this in `TabActivity`. And yes, I think you can with an `OnClickListener` method. But can you post the `TabActivity` class, the code you have to find an appropriate solution?

Comment: really thank you for taking interest. Now my problem is solved. Actually i am quite busy so I have not put solution here. Soon I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

To close tab, I did following trick & finally it works.

1st I have set one default tab & locally maintaining list of all new tabs.

```
//local list
private LinkedList<String> tabList = new LinkedList<String>();  
//adding tab
TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tab_id);   
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
//making local entry
tabsList.add(tab_id);
```

Then using following code I removes particular tab,

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then picks last tab from local list & switch to that tab using following code,

```
String tabid = tabList.getLast();     
tabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tabid);
```

Last step is not mandatory, but sometimes I didn't get tabHost view properly, if don't switch to another tab. If all tabs are closed, then switch to default tab.

I hope it might useful to you guys also.

If somebody has find better way, please let us know.

Thank you.